# How does Sharepoint determine security for an email sent to a list?

Tags: incoming-email, email-enabled-library

I have a list that is email enabled.  When I check the permissions on the library itself, it says I have contribute rights so I can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.  When I email a document to the list, if I don't have 'Accept e-mail messages from any sender' selected, the email never gets into the list.  When 'Accept e-mail messages based on document library permissions' is selected, the mail item appears in the Drop folder and then the timer service comes around and the item is removed, but never delivered into the list.

I imagine Sharepoint is looking at something in the email and not seeing that my email account is the same as my AD account's email.  But maybe that isn't the case.  Is it described somewhere how Sharepoint determines who can email into a list beyond 'be in the security group'?  How does it parse the message and then do the look up?

**EDIT**

Here's the message from the ULS viewer when document library permissions is on

> An error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail file
>   c:\inetpub\mailroot\drop\ed79adfc01cf76a40000000c.eml. The error was:
>   Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource..

So, it's like it is trying to put the document into the list but can't?  Or does the service that the timer runs under need some sort of rights to AD?

**EDIT**
The x-sender is just x-sender: kndiko@wisc.edu and this resolves to a user in active directory.  In my ULS, when the email is removed from the Drop folder, there are seven entries:

> Found 1 trusted forests: ad.domain.com Found 0 trusted forests Leaving
>   Monitored Scope (SPClaimProvider.FillResolveClaim()). Execution
>   Time=1037.34825236168 Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (SPClaimProviderOperations.ResolveClaim()). Execution
>   Time=1076.94246056412 An error occurred while processing the incoming
>   e-mail file c:\inetpub\mailroot\drop\a63cbe3601cf76b200000012.eml. The
>   error was: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this
>   action or access this resource.. The Incoming E-Mail service has
>   completed a batch.  The elapsed time was 00:00:03.1824817.  The
>   service processed 1 message(s) in total.  Errors occurred processing 1
>   message(s): Message ID: <01e301cf76b2$a6510ea0$f2f32be0$@domain.com>
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-email-delivery). Execution
>   Time=3196.55270432415

**Further Edits**
The server involved is the only web front end and SMTP server.  There is no exchange server as email is handled by an external entity.  There is a central AD server that everyone is authenticated against and has been importing users correctly.  We are using Sharepoint 15.0.4569.1506 with all other servers running that version.  Claims authentication by default to our AD server as well.

No other events in the event log.  Only the same events listed above underneath Microsoft->SharePointProducts->Shared->Operational.

Comment: Any else related to claims in the event logs under Windows Logs > Application or Security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that something is going wrong with the AD lookup.

Are there 2 or more AD accounts that have the same email address?

If so, when SharePoint tries to lookup the user in AD by email address, the system will be unsure of which user sent the email. Authentication will fail and the email will never arrive in the document library.

Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2012/03/21/incoming-emails-into-doclib-does-not-work-when.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that article too.  Unfortunately, the user only resolves to one person in AD and Sharepoint.

Comment: Have you turned on verbose logging and looked at messages appearing in the ULS?

Comment: Yes.  There are seven entries.  I'll update the question with them.

Comment: Seems like a claims authentication issue. You should update your question with some details about your environment (e.g. SharePoint version, authentication). Two questions: 1) Have other users in your domain tried to send email to the library? 2) Are there errors in your Window Application event logs? (especially regarding claims authentication).

Comment: A user from another domain forest had the same email.  D'oh!